# Error 500 on checkout pages

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, error, http-error-500

I'm working on a website that has suddenly started throwing up 500 Errors on the any checkout/cart related pages.

I've run through all of the usual "fixes";

- Permissions changes
- Turning on `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` & `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` in the `index.php` file and that doesn't display any errors
- I've tried upping the memory limits and it's not that either

All I seem to be getting from the `system` log is;

```
2018-04-05T04:41:06+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:41:55+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:42:31+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:42:37+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:42:47+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:42:51+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:43:03+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:43:13+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:43:20+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:44:38+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:44:50+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:44:52+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:44:52+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php'  in /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/app/design/frontend/TEMPLATE/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml on line 69
2018-04-05T04:44:52+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _filterGroupName  in /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/app/design/frontend/TEMPLATE/default/template/manapro/filteradvanced/view.phtml on line 64
2018-04-05T04:44:59+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:45:02+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:45:30+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:48:39+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:48:39+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php'  in /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/app/design/frontend/TEMPLATE/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml on line 69
2018-04-05T04:48:39+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _filterGroupName  in /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/app/design/frontend/TEMPLATE/default/template/manapro/filteradvanced/view.phtml on line 64
2018-04-05T04:49:04+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:49:05+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
2018-04-05T04:49:14+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/headersubscribe.phtml
```

And from the `exception.log` the following;

```
2018-04-05T04:48:39+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Block_Catalog_Media_Js_List' in /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/includes/src/__default.php(28754): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/includes/src/__default.php(28696): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('configurableswa...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/includes/src/__default.php(28731): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('configurableswa...', 'configurableswa...')
#3 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/includes/src/__default.php(28498): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('configurableswa...', 'configurableswa...')
#4 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/includes/src/__default.php(28464): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/includes/src/__default.php(28469): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/includes/src/__default.php(14260): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(148): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/includes/src/__default.php(14334): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#9 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/includes/src/__default.php(18813): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#10 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/includes/src/__default.php(18343): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/includes/src/__default.php(21279): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /var/www/html/ilddirect.com/index.php(85): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

I'm stumped as to what could be causing this error. We recently updated a plugin (Temando) which didn't seem to impact the functionality at all. This morning it started spitting errors so we rolled back the version to the previous (*working*) plugin version and the 500 error was still happening..

This website is running: Magento ver. **1.9.3.1**

I will note; this is an inherited project from previous developers that have taken a considerable time.

Comment: Better check apache or nginx log in /var/log/%your_web_server_name%

Comment: @StepanFurman have checked the logs and there is nothing present in them, even with all error reporting turned on! This truely is a weird one..

Comment: Ok, then try to switch off the most recently installed modules

Comment: Are you using default checkout?

Also Make sure that your php files have the correct permissions. Try 644

Comment: @ChiragRajput it seems the One page checkout is being used. All file permissions have been tried with 644 and 755 but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your magento have compilation enable. Please make it disable and clear cache.

Use Below Steps:

1. Via Magento admin

   Navigate to *System > Tools > Compilation* page and click on Disable button
   Navigate to *System > Cache Management* screen and use Flush Cache button.
2. Via FTP, by editing the `includes/config.php` file

   To disable compilation in Magento, edit `includes/config.php`. comment both line as below :

   ```
   #define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
   #define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
   ```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing yesterday to fix it! Thanks anyways :)